# PHP - Answer Captcha through cURL GET/POST

Tags: curl, captcha

Imagine this Captcha on the external Site:

```
 <img id="sec-string" onclick="reLoadCaptcha(this);" src="captcha.jpg?random=4850737809844572943" alt="Try another" title="Try another">
```

Now i read and store the value of "random" which in this case is "4850737809844572943". 
This is done with cURL GET. 
So now i can display the image on my site via img-tag. 
With an input field i can type in the anwser.

```
 <input type="text" name="captchaInput" value="" id="captchaInput" class="small" autocomplete="off" onpaste="return false;" maxlength="16" tabindex="1" required="required" placeholder="Enter the characters">
```

Now i send it back as cURL POST, together with the rest of the form data.
The var-dump display a correct string, but the result is "Wrong Captcha"

The rest of the form data is valid. In fact also the Captch Input is sent correct.
Its just not accepted or seen as wrong.

Any ideas what could interrupt the execution?

Thanks

EDIT:

I thought about the 2 cURL executions on my site.
First is GET the data like cookie, session, form elements etc. from the extern page.
Second is POST the data, i filled in at my page, to the extern Page.
So does this count as 1 or 2 actual Site-Requests/Actions?!

I mean because of the Captcha and its actuality.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want to forward someone elses captcha on your site?

Comment: So it can be solved... I try something of personal interest. No public code, or code i want to make public. I'm not trieng to kill the captcha. I just want to solve it correct, with human input, from an external site.

Comment: Then simply load their page and solve the captcha.

Comment: The page probably sets a cookie when you load it, and requires that cookie value to be sent back when the captcha is solved.

Comment: Cookie export and import is working! Without cookie i would get a 403 Fordbidden. But thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.

The problem was indeed that there are 2 cURL requests.
And i didnt split them into 2 functions, because my script is single-file.
Kinda logic, but it took me some time to realise it :)

So now the GET-Request is sent when there is no GET data in the URL.
And the POST-Request, if there is a GET data in the URL.

Before there happend a picture reload, because GET-cURL was executed before POST-cURL again.

Captcha done!

Comment: But as a side question: I wonder how to stop this way to work. I mean protect myself from usage of that kind of accessing for example an registration form. With some more work, a proxy system and a nice teamplate, someone could easily missuse this technique to fake a site, trick users to the site, let them create actual real accounts AND log them, if people used the fake site the signup... there mus be a way to deny it, or?

Comment: Well im closing the question, when it lets me (+6hours) If u come up with infos, after that time, i would appriciate if u send me a private message :)

Comment: how can you understand when there is a GET curl or not .. on my script  I have done this thing.  :  first  I curl a login page , then I scan it for asp.net variables like __VIEWSTAT  and then I curl again the login page with post data I gathered before ,  I set the captcha manually cause it remains the same by session for long hours . BUT not working and it throws me an error which say captcha is wrong. what should I do now ?

Comment: you can use PHP to scan if there is post/get data. so just wrap your curl-post request into a form, which will then post all the data also to your local url. now you can use something like "if ( isset($_GET['abc']))" to see if the script runs the first time (no post data) or the 2nd time (with post data). this way u can split up the 2 curl requests, to not run both at 1 call.